# Why is catching errors inside a LOOP causing performance issues?

Tags: postgresql

I had a function with a performance issue:

```
totalCharge := 0;
FOR myRecord IN ... LOOP
    ......
    IF severalConditionsAreMet THEN
        BEGIN

            SELECT t1.charge INTO STRICT recordCharge
            FROM t1
            WHERE t1.id = myRecord.id AND otherComplexConditionsHere;

            totalCharge := totalCharge + recordCharge;

            ...........
        EXCEPTION
             WHEN OTHERS THEN 
                 NULL;
        END;
    END IF;

END LOOP;
```

The function was being called 232 times (not counting the number of times the code from the FOR was accessed).
The IF from the FOR LOOP ended up being accessed 4466 times and was taking 561 seconds to complete all 4466 iterations.

For the particular data set that I had, the IF was always accessed, the SELECT from above never return data and the code was reaching the EXCEPTION branch each and every time. 
I have changed the code to:

```
totalCharge := 0;
FOR myRecord IN ... LOOP
    ......
    IF severalConditionsAreMet THEN

        SELECT t1.charge INTO recordCharge
        FROM t1
        WHERE t1.id = myRecord.id AND otherComplexConditionsHere;

        IF (recordCharge IS NULL) THEN
            CONTINUE;
        END IF;

        totalCharge := totalCharge + recordCharge;

        ...........

    END IF;

END LOOP;
```

Please note that for the table t1, the t1.charge column has a NOT NULL condition defined on it.
This time, the code from the IF takes 1-2 seconds to complete all 4466 iterations.

Basically, all I did was replace the

```
BEGIN
…
EXCEPTION
….
END;
```

With

```
IF conditionIsNotMet THEN
    CONTINUE;         
END IF;
```

Can someone please explain to me why this worked?
What happened behind the scenes?
I suspect that when you catch exceptions inside of a LOOP and the code ends up generating an exception, Postgres can’t use cached plans to optimize that code so it ends up planning the code at each iteration and this causes performance issues.
Is my assumption correct?

Later Edit:

I altered the example provided by Vao Tsun to reflect the case that I want to illustrate.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION initialVersion()
RETURNS VOID AS $$
declare
  testDate DATE;
begin
  for i in 1..999999 loop
    begin
    select now() into strict testDate where 1=0;
    exception when others 
    then null;
    end;
  end loop;
end;
$$ Language plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION secondVersion()
RETURNS VOID AS $$
declare
    testDate DATE;
begin
  for i in 1..999999 loop
    select now() into testDate where 1=0;
    if testDate is null then 
      continue;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
$$ Language plpgsql;

select initialVersion(); -- 19.7 seconds

select secondVersion(); -- 5.2
```

As you can see there is a difference of almost 15 seconds.
In the example that I have provided initially, the difference is bigger because the SELECT FROM t1 runs against complex data and takes more time to execute that the simple SELECT provided in this second example.

Comment: Without seeing the "complex conditions" there's no way of knowing for sure.. however, I believe your complex conditions aren't the same within the loop as they are in the select... that's just my intuition.

Comment: The SELECT has not changed. Neither did the LOOP. As I said in the post, the only change I did, was to replace the

BEGIN
…
EXCEPTION
….
END;

With

IF conditionIsNotMet THEN
    CONTINUE;         
END IF; and after this change, the time needed to run the code decreased from 561 seconds to 1-2 seconds. I am not looking for ideas on how to optimize the code as the code is now running smoothly. I want to understand why this change brought such a big time improvement.

Comment: Incorrect. the Select changed to a select STRICT. Which, when removed, is not causing the exception to fire off. Leads me to believe that your initial condition (in the IF) is doing something different from the select strict part-- leading to the IF returning TRUE and the Select likely returning no results or somehow having another exception.

Comment: What I meant to say is that the conditions from the SELECT have not changed. Indeed, I have changed the SELECT ... INTO STRICT.... to a SELECT ... INTO ..... because I did not want the SELECT to throw the NO_DATA_FOUND exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question [here](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Catching-errors-inside-a-LOOP-is-causing-performance-issues-td5985584.html), in the PostgreSQL - general mailing group and got some responses that elucidated this "mystery" for me:

David G. Johnston:

> "​[Tip](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING): A block containing an EXCEPTION clause is significantly
>   more expensive to enter and exit than a block without one. Therefore,
>   don't use EXCEPTION without need."
>
> I'm somewhat doubting "plan caching" has anything to do with this; I
>   suspect its basically that there is high memory and runtime overhead
>   to deal with the possibilities of needing to convert a exception into
>   a branch instead of allowing it to be fatal.

Tom Lane:

> Yeah, it's about the overhead of setting up and ending a
>   subtransaction. That's a fairly expensive mechanism, but we don't have
>   anything cheaper that is able to recover from arbitrary errors.

and an addition from David G. Johnston:

> [...] setting up the pl/pgsql execution layer to trap "arbitrary SQL-layer
>   exceptions"​ is fairly expensive.  Even if the user specifies specific
>   errors the error handling mechanism in pl/pgsql is code for generic
>   (arbitrary) errors being given to it.

These answers helped me understand a bit how things work.
I am posting this answer here 'cause I hope that this answer will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

with given details - cant reproduce:

```
t=# do
$$
declare
begin
  for i in 1..999999 loop
    perform now();
/*    exception when others then null; */
    if null then null; end if;
  end loop;
end;
$$
;
DO
Time: 1920.568 ms
t=# do
$$
declare
begin
  for i in 1..999999 loop
    begin
    perform now();
    exception when others then null;
    end;
  end loop;
end;
$$
;
DO
Time: 2417.425 ms
```

as you can see with 10 millions iterations the difference is clear, but insignificant. please try same test on your machine - if you get same results, you need to provide more details...

Comment: As I said, for my first example, the SELECT ...INTO STRICT never return data and the code was reaching the EXCEPTION branch each and every time. Your code never reaches the exception branch. I have altered your code and added it to the question. Thanks :)